# How does clang Diagnostics get source code?

Tags: clang, llvm

I have a C file <ask.c> :

```
int func(int i) {
    return i;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int j = func(i);
    return j;
}
```

When I try to compiler ask.c by command <clang ask.c -Wall>, I get a warning like

```
ask.c:7:18: warning: variable 'i' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    int j = func(i);
                 ^
ask.c:6:10: note: initialize the variable 'i' to silence this warning
    int i;
         ^
          = 0
1 warning generated.
```

Obviously this variable is indeed not initialized. When I went to explore how clang issued this warning, I found that it was through Diagnostics. The code of clang is as follows：

```
S.Diag(Use.getUser()->getBeginLoc(), diag::warn_uninit_var)
    << VD->getDeclName() << IsCapturedByBlock
    << Use.getUser()->getSourceRange();
```

define in Diagnostic*Kinds.td:

```
def warn_uninit_var : Warning<
  "variable %0 is uninitialized when %select{used here|captured by block}1">,
  InGroup<Uninitialized>, DefaultIgnore;
```

**The exported information is output here, but what surprises me is that the source code of the error location is also output. How clang outputs the source code of the error location?**

> ```
> int j = func(i);
>              ^
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`clang::Sema` (your variable `S` in `S.Diag`) has access to the `clang::SourceManager` which in turn has access to all the raw bytes of all the input files, as well as non-files like macro expansion buffers expanded lazily if needed. The diagnostics printer uses the source manager interface to turn the `clang::SourceLocation` into file:line:col as well as a pointer to the raw bytes so it can print that line, as well as query the source manager to obtain the stack of macro instantiations or #include directives followed if applicable.